# Excel Pivot Table Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have an excel sheet that contains data like that shown below.  I have the pivot table that shows departmental time and percent and an external value of total cost.

How do I create a formula that is part of the pivot table that references the Percent value (which is really hours shown as % of Grand Total) and the external Total Cost cell to create the CostShare column?

```
             Total Cost $1200.00

Dept  Hours  Percent   CostShare
A        10     17%     $ 200.00
B        20     33%     $ 400.00
C        30     50%     $ 600.00
--------------------------------
Total    60    100%     $1200.00
```

I'm sure this is googleable but I seem to keep missing the mark. A link to a page that explains this would be sufficient and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please select one cell of the pivot table > PivotTable Analyze > **Fields, Items & Sets** in Calculations group > Calculated Field.

Then you could change the Name, enter "`=Percent*1200`" for the Formula.

[image]

Change the format for numbers as the following gif.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your data is actually as simple as the table shown, then it's easier to not use a pivot table.

Give your Total cost cell a name by typing into the Name Box

[image: IMG:]

I've named it `total_cost`.

Format your data as a Table. Put your cursor anywhere in the data and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Add a new column called `CostShare`.

Use this formula:

```
=[@Hours]*total_cost/SUM([Hours])
```

It looks like this:

[image: IMG:]

The results look like this:

[image: IMG:]

In the case that your data is actually more complicated than in your post, then if you want to refer to a calculated measure like '% of Column' or '% of Grand Total' in another calculation in the PivotTable, you'll probably need to use the PowerPivot Data Model to create a measure.

The key thing to remember is that the data you're using in the calculation needs to be in the data model using the button on the Power Pivot tab on the ribbon.

So, create a Table as before, but add a column that puts the Total Cost on each row. Like this:

[image: IMG:]

Then, enable the PowerPivot add-in if it's not already enabled, then add the table to the Data Model.

After the PowerPivot window opens, rename the tab "data" (or whatever you choose).

Create three measures (to keep it simple):

A simple measure that's the sum of the hours column:

```
Dept Hours:=SUM([Hours])
```

A measure that calculates the % of column across the Dept dimension:

```
Dept Hours % of Total:=[Dept Hours]/CALCULATE([Dept Hours],ALL(data[Dept]))
```

A measure that calculates Cost share:

```
Cost Share:=[Dept Hours % of Total]*DISTINCT(data[TotalCost])
```

After that, your PowerPivot window should look like this:

[image: IMG:]

And if you then create a pivot table from that, you can set it up to look like this:

[image: IMG:]